# Dojo enhancedgrid sorting problem

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am using Dojo enhancedGrid (1.6) with indirectSelection plugin to generate checkboxes. I am having an issue with row selection and sorting.

Here is how to recreate the problem:

- Check the checkboxes of the first 2 rows
- Sort the grid by clicking on a column
- The sort order of the rows changes, but the first 2 rows are still checked, the checkmark doesn't move with the rows.

This issue is present in both dataGrid and enhancedGrid, even on the Dojo example page.

- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid.html

Is this a bug or is there a way to make the checkbox move with the row when sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it really is.
I'm using dojo 1.7.1 release , and it still has this problem

what's more , when use 
     grid.rowSelectCell.setDisabled(0, true)，
and then use
     dijit.byId("dataGrid").rowSelectCell.toggleAllSelection(true);
the disabled checkboxes will still be selected.

badly, use
     gridDomNode.selection.getSelected();
will still select the rows with disabled checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Hope this still helps.

I had the same issue, and found out it is already solved and patched... (at least from dojo version 1.6)

In short, the only thig you need to do is this.

[in your EnhancedGrid] set '*keepSelection*' attribute to true,

e.g.

```
<div dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" keepSelection = true .../>
```

also, note that there is a precondition: Identifier(id) is required for store, as id is used for differentiating row items

thats it! now any sorting, filtering or pagination actions in the grid will preserve the selections!

More info here:
http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10855

Note: I'm using dojo version 1.6 and the patch mentioned in there is ALREADY applied to the dojo files, so you DO NOT NEED to apply such patch, just add the attribute to the grid, (and ensure your store is identified by the id.)